# Format and append JSON data to html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am using JSON data in my application and here is a sample code of my json data.

```
{  
   "myMenu":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "name":"name 01",
         "image":"img_url",
         "other":[  
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_01"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_02"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_03"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_04"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_05"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "name":"name 02",
         "image":"img_url",
         "other":[  
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_01"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_02"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_03"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_04"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_05"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"3",
         "name":"name 03",
         "image":"img_url",
         "other":[  
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_01"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_02"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_03"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_04"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_05"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to get one id data into a row.

Assume id 1 data, I need to show id 1 data and its other 5 data in one row. Then id 2 data, like wise.

This is the way I am looking this output,

```
        <!-- id 1 content -->
        <div class="headings">
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
        </div>
        <!-- id 2 content -->
        <div class="headings">
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
        </div>
        <!-- id 3 content -->
        <div class="headings">
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
            <div class="heading"><img src...><name></div>
        </div>
```

This is what I tried,

```
            $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { 

                $.each(data.myMenu, function(key, value) {

                    $('#content').append('<div class="headings"></div>');                                                       
                    $('.headings').append('<div class="heading"><img src="'+ value.image +'" alt="name" /></div>');

                    $.each(value.other, function(key, value) {

                        $('.headings').append('<div class="heading"><img src="'+ value.image +'" alt="name 2" /></div>');

                    });

                }); 
            });
```

Comment: what is `<name>` supposed to be?

Comment: @DelightedD0D it is the name value getting from the json

Comment: So you're actually wanting "name_01" etc to be there not `<name>`?

Comment: yes of course, I just noted there I need to show the name "name_01" etc...

Comment: I'm sure you can understand that choosing to note that there with the syntax `<name>` was a bit misleading...

Comment: @DelightedD0D Sorry about that and <name> is the text name and it is NOT a TAG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95299/discussion-between-user2584538-and-delightedd0d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is write a couple of loops to iterate through your arrays. Here's a sample solution using [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var obj = {  
   "myMenu":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "name":"name 01",
         "image":"img_url",
         "other":[  
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_01"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_02"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_03"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_04"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_05"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "name":"name 02",
         "image":"img_url",
         "other":[  
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_01"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_02"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_03"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_04"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_05"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"3",
         "name":"name 03",
         "image":"img_url",
         "other":[  
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_01"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_02"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_03"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_04"
            },
            {  
               "image":"img_url",
               "name":"name_05"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};

obj.myMenu.forEach(function(item) {
  var element = $('<div class="headings"><img src="' + item.image + '">' + item.name + '</div>');
  item.other.forEach(function(otherItem) {
    var otherElement = $('<div class="heading"><img src="' + otherItem.image + '">' + otherItem.name + '</div>');
    element.append(otherElement);
  });
  $("body").append(element);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Here I need to show my name and image on main IDs too. In your solution other data appending correctly. But it is not appending parent content.

Comment: How do you want the parent content to show? You don't have it in your example output.

Comment: that is fine. I made it. I mean to add myMenu -> id* -> image/name then the other content
I made the change adding,
      var mainId = $('<div class="channel heading"><img src="' + item.image + '"></div>');
      element.append(mainId); after var element.:)

Comment: I updated the answer. I think it's how you want it now.

Comment: Yes. That is what I wanted. Thanks Dave.